# Problem making ros gazbeo module with velodyne_pointcloud

Tags: ros, ros-jade, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using ROS jade and I needed velodyne package for my module. So I used the tutorial describe in http://answers.ros.org/question/226594/how-do-i-build-ros-vlp16-velodyne-driver-for-indigo-using-catkin/

and built velodyne package for ROS Jade.
After that when I do catkin_make

I get following errors:

-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/jade/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"velodyne_pointcloud" with any of the following names:

```
velodyne_pointcloudConfig.cmake
velodyne_pointcloud-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "velodyne_pointcloud" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
or set "velodyne_pointcloud_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
files.  If "velodyne_pointcloud" provides a separate development package or
SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
azcar_sim/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/jane/ros15/trunk/gazebo_workspace/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/jane/ros15/trunk/gazebo_workspace/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1

I don't know how to fix that. Can somebody help me?

Thanks.
Rahul

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227685/problem-making-ros-gazbeo-module-with-velodyne_pointcloud./) by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 234 on 2016-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, so I realized that my module and velodyne package that I had downloaded from git were in different catkin workspace. I resolved it by downloading and making velodyne package in same catkin workspace.

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) with karma: 234 on 2016-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0